# Laravel method not recieving post data on $request

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

On Laravel 5.1 a method is not recivieng the post data.

This is my method where $request does not store the data sent by post.

```
class ProjectCommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request,$projectId)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'description' => ['required'],
        'status' => ['required'],
        'profile_id' => ['required']
    ]);

    $project = Project::findOrFail($projectId);

    return $project->comments()->save(new Comment([
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'status' => $request->input('status'),
        'profile_id' => $request->input('profile_id')
    ]));
    }
}
```

This is how I call it from my test:

```
public function testProjectCommentCreation()
{
$category = factory(\App\Category::class)->create();

$project = factory(\App\Project::class)->create([
    "category_id" => $category->id
]);

$profile = factory(\App\Profile::class)->create();


$comment = factory(\App\Comment::class)->make([
    "profile_id"=>$profile->id
]);

$this->post(route('api.projects.comments.store', ['projects' => $project->id]), $comment->jsonSerialize(), $this->jsonHeaders)
    ->seeInDatabase('comments', ['project_id'=>$project->id,'description'=>$comment->description])
    ->assertResponseOk();
 }
```

This is what $comment->jsonSerialize() stores:

```
array(3) {
'description' =>
string(10) "zFG8bW7EIz"
'status' =>
string(6) "active"
'profile_id' =>
int(629)
}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::resource('projects.comments','ProjectCommentController',['only'=>['index','store']]);
```

My method recieves $projectId from the URL and that is working but the request comes empty, without the data I send from $comment->jsonSerialize()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was solved by removing the header

```
Content-type: application/json
```

I'm still not sure why it is not working with that header but it was not an error on the method or the test.

Comment: I was facing similar issue and this has helped me too. This issue is on Apache only and while using `php artisan serve` it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
$this->post(route('api.projects.comments.store', ['projects' => $project->id]), $comment->toArray())
    ->seeInDatabase('comments', ['project_id'=>$project->id,'description'=>$comment->description])
    ->assertResponseOk();
```

Does anything show if you put `dd($request->all());` in your store method?

Comment: The output was [] but for some reason after I removed the header Content-type application/json it worked